# How to print server execution time and roundup time after query execution in RethinkDB?

Tags: rethinkdb, reql

Is there any easy way to print **server time** and **round-trip time** after execution Query complete in Javascipt? I have seen this in webadmin, but could not found in API. For the Benchmarking purpose of Query, which one should we consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to Jorge's answer about measuring round-trip time:
You can obtain the server time from the query profile. This is also what the Data Explorer (web UI) uses.

Profiling must be enabled by passing the `{profile: true}` optarg into `run`.
As a result, you get an object with the profile in a `profile` field, and the query result in a `value` field of the result.

For example in JavaScript:

```
r.expr("test query").run(conn, {profile: true}, function(err, result) {
   var serverTime = result.profile[0]['duration(ms)'];
   console.log(serverTime);
 });
```

Comment: Regarding which one to use for benchmarking: It depends on what exactly you want to measure. If your client hardware and configuration is identical to what you'll use in your actual production setup, measuring round-trip time gives you a more realistic timing that includes overhead for the transferring the result over the network and for decoding it on the client. If on the other hand you want to measure server performance only (e.g. your client setup isn't final yet), server time might be more useful.

Answer (score 1):

For **round-trip time** you can just use the console, by using the `.time` and `.timeEnd` methods.

Example:

```
console.time('query');
r.table('table_name')
 .filter({ name: 'jorge' })
 .run(conn)
 .then(function (cursor) {
   console.timeEnd('query');
 });
```

You can find the documentation for these methods in MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/timeEnd